# Create action for button over modal segue. Unable to ctrl drag, Swift

Tags: swift, button, modal-dialog, action, segue

Im trying to get a button to take me to a hyperlink, this button is located on an "About" page for my app. I have the following code which I know should do the job but I am unable to ctrl drag from the button and onto the "ViewController.Swift" file to create an action:

```
@IBOutlet weak var hyperLink: UIButton!

@IBAction func hyperLink(sender: UIButton!) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Here is a pic of my storyboards, the button hyperlink I want to place is in the bottom left window:

[image]

New to Swift so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the View Controller in which you placed the button doesn't confirm to the custom class that you use.

[image: xcode]

**Also, you can track where did you get your nil error above the terminal window:**
[image: error message]

Comment: I thought that too, however when I change it and run my app it crashes when it gets to the about page. Error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." Any idea why? The about page is presented modally from a popover menu

Comment: When it crashes, you can see where you get an optional above the terminal. Can you give more information, where do you get this error?

Comment: Seem like you have deleted some UI controls that you previously bound by actions.  that its says " nil while unwrapping an Optional value". for varios reason this can be occor

Comment: @AntonZobnin "->  0x1001e476c <+44>:  brk    #0x1 , Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint (Code=1, subcode=0x1001e476c)" That is what is displayed on the highlighted line, not sure if it is useful

Comment: @chamathjeevan is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Anton 0 specialised_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, Uint) -> ()

Comment: @chamathjeevan Sure, can we take this to pm somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button action programmertically as below.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
```

Else try go last tab of the inspector panel and drag the relevant method/Action to element on object panel on the storyboard.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you give me more insight on where this would go in correlation with my code for the action? I am new to swift so it is hard to grasp fully

Comment: Add it in to viewdidLoad

Comment: Thanks, the About page isn't in the same class so this wouldn't work. When I try to change the class name to the same name it crashes on the About page :( Any idea why?